# ES6 Create a writeLong method

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm currently experimenting with bytes. I wan't to write `Short` and `Long` values to a `String`.

The original output in `HEX` from `Java` (not JavaScript!) as follows:

> 00 15 FF FF FF FF FF FF D0 3F

But when i create the same in `JavaScript` the `writeLong` work's not correctly:

> 00 15 EE 47 AF 15 EE 47 AF 15

And here is my working JSFiddle

```js
class BufferWriter {
 constructor(buffer) {
  this._buffer = buffer;
 }
 
 /*
 00 15 FF FF FF FF FF FF D0 3F
 */
 
 writeByte(value) {
  this._buffer.append(value & 0xFF);
 }
 
 writeInt(value) {
  [ 24, 16, 8, 0 ].forEach(function(shift) {
   this.writeByte(value >>> shift);
  }.bind(this));
 }
 
 writeShort(value) {
  [ 8, 0 ].forEach(function(shift) {
   this.writeByte(value >>> shift);
  }.bind(this));
 }
 
 writeLong(value) {
  [ 56, 48, 40, 32, 24, 16, 8, 0 ].forEach(function(shift) {
   this.writeByte(value >>> shift);
  }.bind(this));
 }
}

class Buffer {
 constructor() {
  this._buffer = [];
 }
 
 append(data) {
  console.log(data, String.fromCharCode(data));
  this._buffer.push(data);
 }
 
 toString() {
  return String.fromCharCode.apply(null, this._buffer);
 }
 
 toHEX() {
  return Array.prototype.map.call(this._buffer, function(byte) {
   return ('0' + (byte & 0xFF).toString(16)).slice(-2);
  }).join('').toUpperCase();
 }
 
 getSize() {
  return this._buffer.length;
 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <title>DEV</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <script type="module">
   var buffer = new Buffer();
   var writer = new BufferWriter(buffer);

   writer.writeShort(21);
   writer.writeLong(-297292011);

   console.log(buffer, buffer.toString(), buffer.toHEX());
  </script>
  <script nomodule>
   alert('Your Browser don\'t use new techniques - Please upgrade or download Opera, Firefox or Chrome!');
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: There simply are no 64 bit integers in JS ([yet](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-bigint)) that you could write. And `>>>` operates on uint32 (after casting the 64-bit-float to that), that's why you get those weird results.

Comment: `-297292011` as uint32 in hexadecimal is `15AF47EE`. The repeat is because of operating on 32bit integers and the following step (common in many languages when using shifts): `Let shiftCount be the result of masking out all but the least significant 5 bits of rnum, that is, compute rnum & 0x1F`

Comment: How i can fix that?

Comment: Sorry for some confusion that might have arisen because i wrote the hex in little endian, that was perhaps not the smartest. Anyways, if you want to do 64bit, you will need to make/use a library that simulates it. About the result, i don't understand your java result if anything. As a hint, you can see java's result only differs from `FF` on the last two bytes, meaning it cannot be more than UINT_16_MAX (65535) away from -1. Which does not match your input.

Comment: My misunderstand ist, why i can "simulate" it - Give's `ArrayBuffer` and their `TypedArrays` these option? I don't want third-party librarys - And the most **uses** `Node.js` - i don't want it for the client side.